# Isotope filter not showing/hiding specific classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I have spent many hours on trying to get this to work and have no luck.

I followed the documentation here:
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html

So basically what I want to do is show anything that has the class 'box' and hide everything else. I added this line of code to the JS:

```
$('.items').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    filter: '.box' 
});
```

I have tried other JS lines of code, including this one:

```
$container.isotope({
    filter: '.box'
});
```

None of them seem to work.

Here is my (partial) HTML:

```
<div class="metro-layout vertical">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>My Street Life</h1>
        <div class="controls">
            <span class="down" title="Scroll down"></span>
            <span class="up" title="Scroll up"></span>
            <span class="next" title="Scroll left"></span>
            <span class="prev" title="Scroll right"></span>
            <span class="toggle-view" title="Toggle layout"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content clearfix">
        <div class="items">
            <a class="temp" href="#" style="background: #E67E22;">
                <span>Music</span>
                <img height="150px" width="150px" class="icon" src="images/my-music.png" alt="" />
            </a>
            <a class="box" href="#" style="background: #1ABC9C;">
                <span>TV &amp; Movies</span>
                <img height="150px" width="150px" class="icon" src="images/my-movies.png" alt="" />
            </a>
```

Here is my (partial) JS:

```
$(function() {

// get elements to increase speed
$layout = $('.metro-layout');
$container = $('.metro-layout .content');
$('.items').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    filter: '.box' 
});


// this method should be called when you want to switch the layout style - horizontal or vertical
function changeLayoutMode(isHorizontal) {
    $('.items',$layout).removeAttr('style'); // clean style
    if ( isHorizontal ) {
        $('.items',$layout).css({
            width: $('.items',$layout).outerWidth() // make sure we get the whole width of the items container
        }).isotope({
            itemSelector : '.box',
            layoutMode: 'masonryHorizontal',
            animationEngine : 'css'
        });
    } else {
        $('.items',$layout).css({ width: 'auto' }).isotope({
            itemSelector : '.box',
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            animationEngine : 'css'
        });
    }
}
changeLayoutMode($layout.hasClass('horizontal')); // init initial state based on the class in the markup
```

I don't think you will need the full code, but if you feel you do please let me know.

Also, If you need more info from me or my question is not clear please let me know. With that being said can someone assist me with this issue?

Here is the link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikev10/r229k3j0/2/ notice to the far right the 'Music' box is still there even though it has a class of 'temp'

Comment: A JSFiddle would go a long way.

Comment: @Jason Here is the link to JSFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/mikev10/r229k3j0/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/mikev10/r229k3j0/2/) notice to the far right the 'Music' box is still there even though it has a class of 'temp'

Comment: Isn't working. You aren't loading the isotope Javascript file. See you Javascript console for errors.

Comment: @Jason can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: You included jQuery as an external resource. However, you did not include isotope javascript file as a external resource. So you are getting Javascript errors. You'll need to add isotope as an external resource (cdnjs.com has it available to link to).

Comment: @Jason I have now also included the only other file i have in my code. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikev10/r229k3j0/3/) it is still not working.

Comment: jQuery was being loaded after isotope, not before. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it isn't filtering is because isotope only filters items it is in control of. The `itemSelector` is `.box` and the `filter` is `.box`. It won't remove the `.temp` item because it isn't loaded into isotope. Below is a working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/r229k3j0/6/

You'll notice that the `itemSelector` is now `.item` and I added that class to all of the elements inside of `.items`. Appears to behave as you intend.

Comment: That worked, but it resizes the height of the box to about 10 px. it is adding this style: `width: auto;height: 0px;` to the items div. Also, if I switch it to horizontal it will show the box again and keep everything resized.

Comment: Unsure why it is doing that; it'd probably be best to ask that as a new question as it is unrelated to the original question.

Comment: Thanks! I will ask a new question.

Comment: I made a mistake and forgot to add `item` as a part of the class for all of the elements inside of .items. It seems to be working